# Why are db_nmap results filtered, but Nmap is not

Tags: nmap, kali-linux

I've recently started playing with Kali on VMWare Player and Metasploitable 2 on VmWare Player. Both are on the same (default install) subnet. Metasploitable 2 has 2 adapters: settings:NAT and Host only, while Kali has only NAT.

If I run Nmap from Kali outside MSFConsole I get open ports:

```
root@kali:~# nmap -p0-65535 192.168.233.129

Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-21 11:41 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.233.129
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
Not shown: 65506 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
23/tcp    open  telnet
25/tcp    open  smtp
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
512/tcp   open  exec
513/tcp   open  login
514/tcp   open  shell
1099/tcp  open  rmiregistry
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2049/tcp  open  nfs
2121/tcp  open  ccproxy-ftp
3306/tcp  open  mysql
3632/tcp  open  distccd
5432/tcp  open  postgresql
5900/tcp  open  vnc
6000/tcp  open  X11
6667/tcp  open  irc
6697/tcp  open  unknown
8009/tcp  open  ajp13
8180/tcp  open  unknown
8787/tcp  open  unknown
40319/tcp open  unknown
44229/tcp open  unknown
52677/tcp open  unknown
55486/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:FA:DD:2A (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.92 seconds
```

When I run db_nmap within MSFConsole I get all ports are filtered:

```
msf > db_nmap -p 1-4000 192.160.233.129
[*] Nmap: Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-21 11:42 EST
[*] Nmap: Nmap scan report for 192.160.233.129
[*] Nmap: Host is up (0.00089s latency).
[*] Nmap: All 4000 scanned ports on 192.160.233.129 are filtered
[*] Nmap: Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 97.35 seconds
```

Before running these commands today I did:

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Yesterday, (I did an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`) I was getting the same Nmap results, but all ports closed on the Metasploitable VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typo?

192.168.x.y vs. 192.160.x.y?